# Will old stable in debian receive non-security updates after the release of stable?

Tags: debian, upgrade

As jessie is released ,wheezy will be provided security updates till 2016.
My question is :Will wheezy receive non-security updates after jessie is released?

Answer (score 3):

The security team provides security updates for any Debian version X until one year after the release of Debian X+1. Until the Debian LTS project began, that meant that at that point, this version X would be no longer supported.

However, Debian LTS has changed this in that the LTS project now ensures versions starting with Debian 6 "squeeze" are supported up to five years after they were released; that is, any Debian X is supported until five years after the release of X. However, this support is limited to the i386 and amd64 architectures, i.e., 32- and 64-bit PC.

Under normal circumstances, only security updates are provided. However, there are some exceptions; e.g., for web browsers, Debian sometimes does update the version in stable releases when upstream ceases support for the version currently in stable or oldstable. Also, things like clamav (virusscanner) and spamassassin may be updated if the stuff they try to defend against has changed sufficiently that their codebase needs to be updated in order to be able to support newly downloaded rules and/or definitions. As such, it may be that such packages are updated in X even after the release of X+1. However, this will not be the case once a Debian version has reached LTS status; the LTS project explicitly excludes such software from its supported packages.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it, according to [the official docs](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable).